# mutation Typings in Vue Apollo v4 and Composition API

Tags: typescript, vue.js, apollo, vue-apollo, vue-composition-api

What would be the correct way to tell typescript, that `Variables` is the interface for the arguments of `myMutation` function?

```js
    interface Variables {
      uuid: string;
      value: string;
    }

    const { mutate: myMutation } = useMutation(myGqlMutation);
```

I want to avoid using myMutation like this:

```js
 myMutation({
     uuid: '....',
     value: '....',
 } as any); // get rid of any here ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Annotate `useMutation` with [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html), like this:

```
interface Variables {
  uuid: string;
  value: string;
}

const { mutate: myMutation } = useMutation<{ mutation: Variables }>(myGqlMutation);
```

Also, check out [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/static-typing/#usemutation)

Comment: seems not to work with my Vue Apollo, since the first arg of of useMutation would be the result type. The .d.ts looks like this:

`
/**
 * Use a mutation that requires variables.
 */
export declare function useMutation<TResult = any, TVariables extends OperationVariables = OperationVariables>(document: DocumentNode | ReactiveFunction<DocumentNode>, options: UseMutationOptionsWithVariables<TResult, TVariables> | ReactiveFunction<UseMutationOptionsWithVariables<TResult, TVariables>>): UseMutationReturn<TResult, TVariables>;
`